# Node.js PageRes doesn't work on certain URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, screen-capture

I have a pretty simple node.js program using [PageRes](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres).  Given a URL, it takes a screenshot.

However, I'm running into issues where it works on some websites but not on others. These are sites that I have access to so if it's a configuration issue I'll have the ability to solve it.  I thought perhaps a `robots.txt` was blocking, but `robots.txt` is allowing all traffic.

Here is the code, which is pretty boilerplate for pageres:

```
const pageres = new Pageres({ 
    username: 'username', 
    password: 'password',  
    delay: 5, 
    filename: '<%= url %> - <%= date %>'
})
    .src('http://stage.website.com/en-my', ['1920x1080']
    .dest(__dirname)
    .run()
    .then(() => console.log('done'));
```

I receive no error message.  The program runs, then just stops.

I assume this is a server configuration issue since I can get this to work on some sites and not others but I'm not sure what sort of configuration to look for.

Comment: You might want to use a `.catch()` handler at the end to see if there are any reported errors.

Comment: do you have an example of how to add a .catch() in that scenario? I've looked around for node.js error handling and haven't really found something like this.

Comment: `.run()` just returns a normal promise so you can just add the `.catch()` to the end of promise chain: `.run().then(() => console.log('done')).catch(err => console.log(err))`